# Magento2: How to make page non-cacheable in cms

Tags: magento, magento2

I have added below code to load custom template file from a cms page.

`{{block class="Test\PointHistory\Block\Index" template="Test_PointHistory::index.phtml"}}`

I want to get the latest data every time I reload this cms page but it always returns data from full page cache.

Can anyone look into this and suggest me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve this issue.
The steps I took to resolve this issue are as follows:

1. Create a new page layout that inherits Magento's default page layout. Example

   ```
   app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column-disabled-fpc.xml`
   ```

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <update handle="1column"/>
       <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
           <container name="one-column-disabled-cache" as="one-column-disabled-cache" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="disabled-fpc" />
       </referenceContainer>
   </layout>
   ```
2. Create file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
   ```

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="one-column-disabled-cache">
               <block name="disabled-fpc" cacheable="false"/>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. Create file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml
   ```

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
       <layout id="1column-disabled-fpc">
           <label translate="true">1 column (Disabled FPC)</label>
       </layout>
   </page_layouts>
   ```
4. Go to the Admin and change the layout of the CMS page to `1 column (Disabled FPC)`

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `getCacheLifetime()` method in your block class to return null.

Comment: Thanks. I tried applying it but not working for me.v

Answer (score 0):

You have to override this `getCacheLifetime()` with:

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return null;
}
```

The other way (better) is to impletement the `IdentityInterface`

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/develop/identity-class.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried applying it but not working for me.